# Подскажите как сверстать такой елемент?

Tags: html, css, изображения, style, png

Подскажите как сверстать такой елемент(popular)!!!! Пожалуйста

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 1):

Просто используйте `transform: rotate(45deg);` в связке с `overflow: hidden;`

```css
body {
  background: #555;
}

.block {
  height: 300px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #222;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.block__bage {
  padding: 2px 0;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background: red;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  right: -25px;
  top: 15px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block__bage">
    popular
  </div>
</div>
```